# Check if time is between two values in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to get something like below in SQL

```
if (current time in between 5AM to 3PM )
then print "firsshift"
else (current time in between 5AM to 3PM)
then print "second shift"
```

Comment: you have given same time slot for both the conditions.is this correct?

Comment: Formatting, grammar.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @CurrentTime AS TIME

SET @CurrentTime = GETDATE()

SELECT @CurrentTime AS CurrentTime,
CASE 
    WHEN @CurrentTime BETWEEN '5:00:00' AND '15:00:00' THEN
        'First Shift'
    ELSE
        'Second Shift'
END AS WhichShift
```

Comment: Although you don't really need to declare a variable to do this, you can just replace `@CurrentTime` with `GETDATE()`. It would tidy up your code, a bit =)